# R vs. OneDrive directory name

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, onedrive

I'm using Microsoft R 3.3.1 under Windows 10, and am experiencing a problem with using R and Microsoft OneDrive for Business.

Consider the following:

```
> dir()
...
[31] "OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune"
...
> setwd(dir()[31])
> setwd("..")
> setwd("OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune")
Error in setwd("OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune") : 
cannot change working directory
> p <- getwd(dir()[31])
> r <- "OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune"
> p
[1] "OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune"
> r
[1] "OneDrive – Innherred Samkommune"
> p == r
[1] FALSE
```

It turns out that substr(p,10,10) does not match substr(r,10,10). That's the "-". But behold:

```
> pp <- substr(p,10,10)
> rr <- substr(r,10,10)
> pp == rr
[1] FALSE
> charToRaw(pp)
[1] 96
> charToRaw(rr)
[1] 96
```

Apparently, something is very odd about the "-" that Microsoft provides.  it is not obvious that it is an encoding problem. No, the "-" is hardcoded, no register trickery can do anything about it.

Any and all suggestions welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: What does `all.equal(pp, rr)` return?

Comment: I see a `-` and a `–` in your question. Those are obviously different characters.

Comment: all.equal(pp,rr) returns [1] "1 string mismatch"

Comment: I copied the dashes from your question: `charToRaw("-")` returns `[1] 2d`, 
`charToRaw("–")` returns `[1] 96`

Comment: Don't mind the dashes from the questions, they are identical in the raw code. Windows tries to be cute when copying and pasting.

Comment: Then you need to provide a reproducible example.

Comment: I've updated the code now. The above is reproducible.

Comment: The same error message applies when using both versions of the -. This still stands: setwd(p) works, setwd(r) doesn't. Print p and r, the displayed text is equal, but p != r all the same.

Comment: No, it's not. "reproducible" means that I can copy your code, run it, and see the same output as yuo.

Comment: Does the folder actually exist? Have you actually checked that you are in the correct folder? Have you typed the folder name correctly? Have you tried copying the folder's name from Explorer *directly*? Quite obviously something went wrong the first time and you got at least one wrong character in there. You probably have more. Did you copy the folder name to some editor that formatted it first, eg Word?

Comment: Roland, 

I don't think the code is reproducible in the sense you mean unless you have a Microsoft OneDrive Business account. Because it's only with that particular folder I experience this.

Comment: Panagiotis, please read the question. All the questions you ask can be answered by reading the question.

Comment: Well - this type of error are often quite hard to solve - when it's dependant on your enviroment (I get no error when running the code you submitted, obviously). Since we don't know enough we can only speculate. Perhaps an encoding error somewhere?

Comment: I've looked into the problem from the shell now. It seems that if I create a directory with an "-", then no problem. But the dir command (from the Windows shell) suggests that the "-" is not the "-" that you type in from the keyboard as far as the "-" in the name of the OneDrive folder si concerned.

So perhaps Windows is being cute and switches between internal and external representation. Then that's probably something that the R developers should know about.